# What is the strategy for application load page from database?

Tags: angular, ionic3

I’m trying to make an application that store HTML in SQLite database.

I’m using **ionic 3** to make this app and i’m new to Angular 4, I’m more familar with angularjs.

Until now, I known how to get HTML from SQLite, but I still don’t how can I pass it into an ionic 3 Page dynamically.

I want to do that because i want to implement the searching function for my HTML content.

Please help me.

Comment: For this use case Angular 2 or later isn't a good fit. You can use Angular to build the main application and integrate such dynamically loaded pages using a different binding library or whatever, not use Angular at all.
Angular is optimized for ahead-of-time compilation, that doesn't work well with dynamically loaded HTML (at least if this loaded HTML contains Angular-specific markup). There is a way to do it though. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38888008/how-can-i-use-create-dynamic-template-to-compile-dynamic-component-with-angular

Comment: Thanks Günter Zöchbauer! If I implement all HTML template to page without SQLite dynamically load, Can I make a text search through all compiled pages in Angular?

Comment: Not sure what you mean? What kind of text search? The HTML is stored in the build output, but bindings are resolved only at runtime.

Comment: I mean, I want to have a universal search the contain of all pages to see what page have the search keywords. Can I?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what "universal search" means.

Comment: I mean search in the contain of all compiled page .

Comment: I don't think there is much difference to any other web framework. I haven't done anything like that myself yet. Angular itself doesn't provide anything by itself.

Comment: Thank you so much, I'll find an other solutions.